# Android: Splash screen problem

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen

I created a splash screen using the follow code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);

    Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while (_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    if (_active) {
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {
                _active = false;
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MyMainActivity.class));
            }
        }
    };

    splashThread.start();
}
```

there is an image view in splash_layout, after the splash screen appears for some time duration, and disappears then MyMainActivity starts, the problem is, after the splash disappears and before MyMainActivity starts, I could see previous screen(irrelevant to my app, e.g. desktop with widgets, or previous running app), how to make the transition fluent so that splash screen directly goes to MyMainActivity?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your reference, here is a best example for [Android - Splash Screen example](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-loading-welcome-splash-spash-screen-example).

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this i am not sure this is 100% work but try may be helpful..

```
protected int _splashTime = 3000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_layout);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MyMainActivity.class));
        }
    }, _splashTime);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried it, the result is the same, I could still see desktop or previous application when the splash disappears before the activity starts.

Comment: I modified the layout file, now it works, I added black background color to the image's parent linearlayout.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `finish()` after `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final long SPLASH_SCREEN_MS = 2500;

private long mTimeBeforeDelay;
private Handler mSplashHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
    // Create a new Handler.
    mSplashHandler = new Handler();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // The first time mTimeBeforeDelay will be 0.
    long gapTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - mTimeBeforeDelay;
    if (gapTime > SPLASH_SCREEN_MS) {
        gapTime = SPLASH_SCREEN_MS;
    }
    mSplashHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            SplashScreenActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, gapTime);
    // Save the time before the delay.
    mTimeBeforeDelay = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSplashHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code:1

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageView splashImageView;
    boolean splashloading = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        splashImageView = new ImageView(this);
        splashImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        splashImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        setContentView(splashImageView);
        // interesting music
        /**
         * Gets your sound file from res/raw
         */
        splashloading = true;
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                splashloading = false;
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }

        }, 3000);

    }
```

Best of luck!